# How to add data to database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How can I add data to my database?

My form:

```
from django import forms

class DinnerForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and model:

```
class Dinner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

my view:

```
def add_dinner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DinnerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
```

How can I save my data to the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the better option for you is to use FormModels. To add something to database :

```
### example
def add_dinner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DinnerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            diner = Dinner.objects.create(
                            name = name,
                            text = text,)
```

Comment: Using FormModel doesn't need to create the object explicity, It can be done by just `form.save()`

Answer (score 0):

if you dont use ModelForm , simply you can do sth like this :

```
def add_dinner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DinnerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            query = Dinner(name = name , text = text)
            query.save()
```